# C# graphics calculate image and keep it

Tags: c#, graphics, paint

I have seen, that the drawing of two images is time consuming, so I want to reduce drawing these images as much as possible. I use pictureedit and have overriden the ondraw event.
Here I added the below part, but it ends up uin a black image. I do want to check, whether I need to draw at all. This check works. Then I draw the background and overlay it by another one and I want to store this as image and put it as background for my control.

If I do not redraw the background I just call:

`g.Clear(Color.Transparent);`

in my pictureEdit paint event.

Did I something wrong?

Best Regards,

Patrick

```
//Recalculate the background
if (redrawBackground)
{
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, backGroundImage.Width, backGroundImage.Height);
    g.Clear(Color.White);
    //this is drawn without aspect ration. The matrix is stored, since drawing images is expensive
    GenerateTransformation(g, false);

    g.DrawImageUnscaled(backGroundImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, backGroundImage.Width, backGroundImage.Height));
    lastTransformation = g.Transform;

    GenerateTransformation(g, true);

    g.DrawImage(foreGroundImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, backGroundImage.Width, backGroundImage.Height));
    lastTransformationAspect = g.Transform;
    //Save bitmap as background
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(backGroundImage.Width, backGroundImage.Height, e.Graphics);
    //Trick the background by a new image
    pictureEdit.Image = bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code (`new Bitmap(backGroundImage.Width, backGroundImage.Height, e.Graphics);`
) does not copy the image to the Bitmap; it only associates the Graphics object with the bitmap.

Try this:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.DrawSomething(); // This draws to the bitmap
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought that my code should have copied from one source to the other. Now I render the background images directly in a button, if the size of it has changed. This reduces the cost of drawing a lot. My profiler showed me, that drawing the background images in pint at any time, was the most time consuming part of code.